# Set param type to one of multiple constant arrays and filter it

Tags: typescript

The first param is a list of allowed strings that the user can use. It works fine.

The second param is an array of values, but it must be one of the multiple arrays of constants defined in the type. It works fine until I call methods like `includes` or `indexOf` on it. When I do it tells me that `field` is of type `never` and I want to understand why and how to make it work properly.

The commented code works fine (kind of a manual job of `includes` or `indexOf`), but it's not ideal and makes me even more confused on why the original doesn't work.

My code:

```js
type AvailableConfigFields = ("a" | "b" | "c" | "more fields")[];
type AvailableProviderFields = ["a"] | ["b"] | ["c"];

function filterFieldsForProvider(
  requestedFields: AvailableConfigFields,
  providerFields: AvailableProviderFields
) {
  // When calling `.includes(field)` TS throws the error below:
  // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  return requestedFields.filter((field) => providerFields.includes(field));

  // The code below works fine, but obviously I don't want to do that

  // return requestedFields.filter((field) => {
  //   let isThere = false;
  //   providerFields.forEach((value) => {
  //     if (value === field) isThere = true;
  //   });
  //   return isThere;
  // });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to some issue with how TypeScript types `Array.prototype.includes`. For an array whose type is a union of non-overlapping constant tuples, the `searchElement` parameter's type is inferred as `never`.

However, if you define your `AvailableProviderFields` type instead as a single Tuple where the element inside is a union of constant types, then TypeScript seems to correctly figure out how to let you use `Array.prototype.includes`.

```
type AvailableConfigFields = ("a" | "b" | "c" | "more fields")[];
type AvailableProviderFields = ["a" | "b" | "c"];

function filterFieldsForProvider(
  requestedFields: AvailableConfigFields,
  providerFields: AvailableProviderFields
) {
  // Argument of type '"a" | "b" | "c" | "more fields"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.
  return requestedFields.filter(
    (field) => (providerFields as string[]).includes(field)
  );
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQMIHsB2AZkgOYBiSEKAJgM5QC8UAFAEQKtQA+Ur6nPVgGMBvALa4ATtGJU6rAJQBtALoBuALAAoUJFiJUGLAAVJuOEmoRJFOfSZL2ovs5Hrt2wgFd8Q4EgIoYhRga1saWjIpU3NLa2ZtKChpAEcvCFpQ6nC6AC59ZDRMHAJickoIgBpEqDAzCysbCryCw2KYhrDm2m0FKABvGoB6IdhJEi8xCHxgKFxCKF1oAHInbl5+deFnCWkg7tZlqCR6fFxZhFpaUnwjaGBcWoRJBCnQyTmFpahVji3NwQiZYAOhq0mAXkk+GSEDSGSyOVowOC7wSWiSAEhmLIaH0GAA+Wr1OJNOzApC+FBeKy0bHNBQ1BSaLQAX20QA)

However, you will still run into the problem of the type `"a" | "b" | "c" | "more fields"` not being able to be assigned to the type `"a" | "b" | "c"`. I'm not sure why you've set these types up to be different here, but if the same strings were available in each that would resolve this problem.

If one set does need to be wider than the other, as in your example, then you may instead find it useful to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to widen the type of `providerFields` to `string[]` so TypeScript has no problem checking to see if it includes any given string:

```
type AvailableConfigFields = ("a" | "b" | "c" | "more fields")[];
type AvailableProviderFields = ["a" | "b" | "c"];

function filterFieldsForProvider(
  requestedFields: AvailableConfigFields,
  providerFields: AvailableProviderFields
) {
  return requestedFields.filter(
    (field) => (providerFields as string[]).includes(field)
  );
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQMIHsB2AZkgOYBiSEKAJgM5QC8UAFAEQKtQA+Ur6nPVgGMBvALa4ATtGJU6rAJQBtALoBuALAAoUJFiJUGLAAVJuOEmoRJFOfSZL2ovs5Hrt2wgFd8Q4EgIoYhRga1saWjIpU3NLa2ZtKChpAEcvCFpQ6nC6AC59ZDRMHAJickoIgBpEqDAzCysbCryCw2KYhrDm2m0FKABvGoB6IdhJEi8xCHxgKFxCKF1oAHInbl5+deFnCWkg7tZlqCR6fFxZhFpaUnwjaGBcWoRJBCnQyTmFpahVji3NwQiZYAOhq0mAXkk+GSEDSGSyOVowOC7wSWiSAEhmLIaH0GAA+Fh1WKNRFQS5QTKSJD4EiqBTAmlCFBeKy0bHNBQ1BSaLQAX20QA)